# Remove/Hide Claims Provider from Relying Party

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

We have a couple of Relying party Trusts configured. They now get all the claims providers when they log in using AD FS.
Is it possible to manage which relying party that sees what claims provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/home-realm-discovery-customization).

> Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName claimapp -ClaimsProviderName
>   @("Fabrikam","Active Directory")

Comment: Thank you! Just what i wanted.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible on ADFS 2.0, or am I missing something as Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust doesn't accept parameter ClaimsProviderName .

Comment: adfs 2.0 not supported this. in adfs 4.0, we can do this as this is supported by this version.